# multiple signature verification inside solana smart contract

Tags: solana

1)Message:
I have a simple plain text message, let's say: "HELLO, WORLD"

2. The abovetext message  signed by private key 1:

```
const keypair1 = solanaWeb3.Keypair.generate(); // generate keypair1
               const publicKey1 = keypair1.publicKey.toBase58();
               const privateKey1 = keypair1.secretKey;
               let sign1 = nacl.sign.detached(MSG, privateKey1);
```

3. The abovetext message  signed by signed by private key 2:

```
         const keypair2 = solanaWeb3.Keypair.generate(); // generate keypair2
              const publicKey2 = keypair2.publicKey.toBase58();
             const privateKey2 = keypair2.secretKey;
              let sign2 = nacl.sign.detached(MSG, privateKey2);
```

4. The next step is that I want to verify the sign1 and sign2 (multiple Signatures) on the Solana smart contract, for which I need to pass the arguments as sign1 and sign2 to  Ed25119 Program instruction and our custom smart contract's instruction
5. My main question is How can i pass sign1 and sign2 both together in Ed25519 Program Instruction at the same time?
6. Here is the Ed25519 Program reference url : https://docs.solana.com/developing/runtime-facilities/programs#ed25519-program
7. I see in Solana docs, that it says that "This program takes an ed25519 signature, public key, and message. Multiple signatures can be verified." If any of the signatures fail to verify, an error is returned.
8. Ed25519 instuction

The instruction's data will include the public key used to sign, the message signed, and the actual signature.
Below is the sample code in javascript for your reference
// Ed25519 instruction

```
let ix01 = anchor.web3.Ed25519Program.createInstructionWithPublicKey(
  {
    publicKey: invoker.publicKey.toBytes(), // The public key associated with the instruction (as bytes)
    message: MSG,  // The message to be included in the instruction (as a Buffer)
    signature: signature, // The signature associated with the instruction (as a Buffer)
    // instructionIndex: 0
  }
)

let ix02 = await program.methods.verifyEd25519(
  //@ts-ignore
  invoker.publicKey.toBuffer(),
  Buffer.from(MSG),
  Buffer.from(signature))
  .accounts({
    sender: invoker.publicKey,
    ixSysvar: anchor.web3.SYSVAR_INSTRUCTIONS_PUBKEY,
  })
  // .signers([invoker])
  .instruction()

let tx = new anchor.web3.Transaction().add(
  ix01, ix02
)
let tx_hash;
try {
  tx_hash = await anchor.web3.sendAndConfirmTransaction(
    connection,
    tx,
    [invoker]
  );
  console.log(" ~ file: ed25519_poc.ts:82 ~ it ~ tx_hash:", tx_hash);

} catch (error) {
  console.log(" ~ file: ed25519_poc.ts:85 ~ it ~ error:", error);
  // assert.fail(`Should not have failed with the following error:\n${error}`);
}
```

I did practicals with 1 Key to sign a message, and I'm able to verify it.Can anyone please guide me through the process of verifying multiple signatures using Ed25519 Program  and implementing it within a custom Solana smart contract?